# Opencv highgui display window

Tags: c++, opencv

I installed opencv and ran few examples.. I can run simple image display program.. (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html ) The image window does not show the coordinates and rgb pixels values as in the this video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=1OJEqpuaGc4. Do anybody know why and how to get the coordinates and rgb values at the bottom of the window as in the exmaple video...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out at last.. opencv library has to be compiled with qt rather than gtk

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually by using a mouse callback:

http://bsd-noobz.com/opencv-guide/45-3-using-mouse

Comment: This is good.. thanks.. but I am curious how that example video has zoom, save etc buttons along with rgb and coordinate values in the display window? Is it something related to highgui version or opengl rendering?